# Replace comma with pipe delimiter within the same file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

The following is the code, this code works fine and I get an output file with pipe as a delimiter. However, I do not want a new file to be generated rather I would like the existing file to be replaced with pipe delimiter instead of comma. Appreciate your inputs. I am new to python and learning it on the go.

```
with open(dst1,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as input_file:
    with open(dst2, 'w',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore', newline='') as output_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, reader.fieldnames,'uft-8', delimiter='|')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: Well, if everything fits in memory, just keep the data and rewrite them after. If not, just do a temp_file

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Usually you'd do it the other way around; write a new file, then atomically replace the original file with the new file only when the new file has been completely written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only truly safe way to do this is to write to a new file, then atomically replace the old file with the new file. Any other solution risks data loss/corruption on power loss. The simple approach is to use [the `tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) to make a temporary file in the same directory (so [atomic replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) will work):

```
import os.path
import tempfile

with open(dst1, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', newline='') as input_file, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', encoding='utf-8', newline='',
                                 dir=os.path.dirname(dst1), delete=False) as tf:
    try:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(tf, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(reader)
    except:
        # On error, remove temporary before reraising exception
        os.remove(tf.name)
        raise
    else:
        # else is optional, if you want to be extra careful that all
        # data is synced to disk to reduce risk that metadata updates
        # before data synced to disk:
        tf.flush()
        os.fsync(tf.fileno())

# Atomically replace original file with temporary now that with block exited and
# data fully written
try:
    os.replace(tf.name, dst1)
except:
    # On error, remove temporary before reraising exception
    os.remove(tf.name)
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are simply replacing a single-character delimiter from one to another, there will be no change in file size or positions of any characters not being replaced. As such, this is a perfect scenario to open the file in `r+` mode to allow writing back the processed content to the very same file being read at the same time, so that no temporary file is ever needed:

```
with open(dst, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as input_file, open(dst, 'r+', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', newline='') as output_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, reader.fieldnames, 'uft-8', delimiter='|')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

EDIT: Please read @ShadowRanger's comment for limitations of this approach.

Comment: There's no guarantee the file size won't change actually. The default quoting rule for the `csv` module is `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`, which only quotes fields if they contain the delimiter, quote character or line terminator; if you change the delimiter from `,` to `|`, fields that previously required quoting due to embedded commas won't be quoted if they don't contain `|`. And if the script is killed partway through (for whatever reason; power loss, program crash, user hits Ctrl-C), you'll end up with a mix of new and old data.

Comment: Good point. I'll leave my answer here still just in case the OP's actual CSV files don't involve any quoted fields and just want something minimal. But I agree that this is not a robust solution in general.

Comment: Note: You could probably fix the file size issue (though not the problems with power loss/crash/Ctrl-C) by adding `output_file.truncate()` after the `writerows` call. Leaves the (relatively unlikely) possibility that the new file data is so much larger that it overwrites part of the file before you get around to buffering the data from the file, but at least it doesn't risk trailing garbage.

Comment: Both the solutions worked. However,I am convinced towards using ShadowRanger's solution Thank you for the help appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi again, On the same note, one of the column in my csv file has data with | in between the data. How shall I remove it.Thankyou!!

Comment: @user11996418 Same idea. Process the content of the dict and write it back with one of the approaches provided by me and ShadowRanger. If you actually "remove" the `|`s in the data rather than replacing them with a different character, the output file will shrink in size, in which case you'll have to add `output_file.truncate()` after writing the rows as ShadowRanger suggested.

Comment: I have tried the following but was not successful.It gives me an error.with open(dst1,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as input_file:
    with open(dst1, 'r+',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore', newline='') as output_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            row[4] = row[4].replace("|", " ")
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, reader.fieldnames,'uft-8', delimiter='|')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(reader)

Comment: If you process the rows on a per-row basis, then you should write each row using `writerow` instead of `writerows`, inside the loop, and do `writeheader` before the loop.

Comment: I hate to ask again...but unable to figure it out.It will be of great help if you could post the code. Thankyou so much !!

Comment: Please post the code you have now (after applying the tips I gave above), so I can see where the problem lies.

Comment: with open(dst1,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as input_file:
    with open(dst1, 'r+',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore', newline='') as output_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=',')

        for row in reader:
            
            row[4] = row[4].replace("|", " ")
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, reader.fieldnames,'uft-8', delimiter='|')
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(reader)

Comment: You should write the current row with `writer.writerow(row)`, and you should do `writer.writeheader()` before the loop.

Comment: with open(dst1,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as input_file:
    with open(dst1, 'r+',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore', newline='') as output_file:

        reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:

            row[4] = row[4].replace("|", " ")
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, reader.fieldnames,'uft-8', delimiter='|')
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(row)

Comment: `reader` is a `DictReader` object, so you should specify the column by name. Also, you should not do `writer.writeheader()` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but if the file is not too big, you can load the file in pandas using `read_csv` & then save it using your desired delimiter using `to_csv` function using whatever delimiter you like. For example -

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(input_file, encoding='utf-8')
data.to_csv(input_file, sep='|', encoding='utf-8')
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This doesn't replace the original file... And even if you change it to do so by passing `input_file` to `to_csv` as well, it does risk data corruption (since it will be rewriting the file in place by truncating it, then writing out the new data, and a crash partway through will lose data). Beyond that, if the OP isn't already using `pandas`, adding it as a dependency is a pretty heavyweight solution.

Comment: Yeah, I do agree with you. But I think it is a neat solution. Thanks for bringing it to my notice